# How to fire a custom intent?

Tags: java, android

I have created a `BroadcastReceiver`. Now how can I launch my custom `Intent` to test the receiver? AFAIK I cannot use Android JUnit test since the test does not have the application `Context` needed to launch an `Intent`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found an even simpler way to do it in the android shell:

```
am broadcast -a action_name
```

Comment: Nice, wasn't aware of that option :)

Answer (score 3):

How about creating a simple test app with a button that fires the Intent when clicked? Might be more elegant ways, but it shouldn't take you more than a minute to set up.